# CSS outline appears only at bottom of element?

Tags: html, css

why in the example bellow, the red outline is appearing only at the bottom?
I already done several changes, but the problem remains.
Take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/ny48t/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the other three sides are outside of the window.

Answer (score 8):

The Outline is drawn to the **outside** of the inner rectangle defined by the Margin. In this case that is also **outside** of the visible space that the element can render in and is "off the page".

Add a margin (say, 5px) and the remained of the outline will become visible.

Answer (score 6):

You need a margin around it so that can see the rest of the border. The browser window cuts it off otherwise.

```
margin: 5px;
```